# NullPointerException in RedisCache class (line number 614). Version 1.8.22

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-redis

Sometimes NullPointerException occurs in RedisCache class (line number 614). Version 1.8.22

Spring Boot version: 1.5.21.RELEASE

Redis Configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "stringJdkTransactionalRedisTemplate")
public RedisTemplate getRedisTemplate(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory);
    redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public static ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
    return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
}

@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHostName(redisHost);
    connectionFactory.setPort(redisPort);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(redisPassword);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

The execution code

```
public void method1() {
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
User contextUser = ((CustomUser)securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getCustomUser();
contextUser.setRegistrationStatus(clientRegistrationStatus);
redisTemplate.opsForHash().put("spring:session:sessions:" + sessionId, "sessionAttr:SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
method2(user);
}

@Transactional
@CacheEvict(value = CacheName.USER_CACHE, key = "'getByEmail.' + #user.email")
public User methood2(@NotNull User user) {
    return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
}
```

SOMETIMES this code throws following exception on the last line of the method1

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: nulljava.lang.NullPointerException: null at
org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$AbstractRedisCacheCallback.waitForLock(RedisCache.java:614) at
org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$AbstractRedisCacheCallback.doInRedis(RedisCache.java:577) at
org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:207) at
org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169) at
org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:157) at
org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.evict(RedisCache.java:280) at
org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.evict(RedisCache.java:269) at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doEvict(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:98) at
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.performCacheEvict(CacheAspectSupport.java:476) at
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.processCacheEvicts(CacheAspectSupport.java:459) at
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:417) at
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:323) at
org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) at
UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d5a15d5.method2(<generated>) at
ClientServiceImpl.method1(ClientServiceImpl.java:248)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the problem was in the "Transactional" flow.
You have two options here: remove "redisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true)" from bean configuration or move the method2() out from any Transactional scope.